# How can I setup header mode?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation's stacknavigator. I want to process the headers of the setting screen for the test headers none, but the code I used now does not work. What is the problem?

```
const SettingStack = createStackNavigator({
  Setting: {
    screen: SettingScreen,
    headerMode: "none",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontSize: 25,
        color: "#373737",
        fontFamily: "NanumSquareRoundEB",
        marginTop: 63,
        alignSelf: "center"
      },
```

Comment: 1) Your brackets are not correctly matched/closed 2) why are you styling a headerTitle when you don't want a header?? Have another look at the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)

Comment: 1. that code is part of full code.
2. I need just for test headermode. but cant run.

Comment: what is the version of react-navigation ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the navigationOptions header to `null`. You can also check out the documentation always on [React navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#header)

> ```
> screen: SettingScreen,
>  headerMode: "none", // I am not sure if you will need this
>  navigationOptions: {
>     header: null,
>   },
> ```